# If I deal 7 cards what is the probability that there is at least one card from each suit.

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion, card-games

I thought that this would be an easy problem,  and it seems really obvious to me that the answer would be:

$$ \frac{\binom{13}{1}^4 \binom{48}{3}}{\binom{52}{7}} $$

but for some reason this comes out to be around $3.69$ which is not a valid probability.

So then I thought of a different approach where instead of $\binom{48}{3}$ I used $48 * 47 * 46$ but this is obviously even larger.

I'm so confused why this approach doesn't work because I've done similar problems before in this manner. I'm assuming there has to be something that I am missing.

I then did some searching on here and came to an answer I'm confident in of $0.5696$ using Inclusion-Exclusion and counting the bad hands so my solution looked like:

$$ 1 - \frac{4\binom{39}{7} - 3!\binom{26}{7} + 4\binom{13}{7}}{\binom{52}{7}} = 0.5696...$$

I understand how the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle works but I'm wondering what events we're unioning here that it's taken into account. I'm also wondering if there is a more straightforward way of calculating the number of good hands where there is at least 1 card from each suit out of the 7 dealt.

Comment: Your formula counts every such set of seven card multiple times. If the seven cards are $4$ spades and one of each other suit, then you've counted the set $4$ times. If the $7$ cards have $s$ spades, $h$ hearts, $d$ diamonds and $c$ clubs then you've counted the set $shdc$ times. This makes it impossible to scale your result to get the actual count.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Do you mean my final result or just my original formula at the top?

Comment: Essentially, your first number counts tuples $(V,s,h,d,c)$ where $V$ is a set of seven cards and $s,h,d,c\in V$ are particular elements that are spades, hearts, diamonds, and clubs.

Comment: Was talking about your first result.

Answer (score 2):

You might have got confused as the binomial coefficients $\binom41$ etc weren't explicitly mentioned, and in fact $\binom42$ was simplified as factorial $3$ which would make confusion worse confounded

Using the symmetry in the deck, the desired count of "good" hands is better written as

$$ \binom{52}7 - \binom41\binom{39}7 +\binom42\binom{26}7 -\binom43\binom{13}7$$

And, of course, as *probability* has been asked for, you can write it as

$$ 1 - \dfrac{\binom41\binom{39}7 -\binom42\binom{26}7 +\binom43\binom{13}7}{\binom{52}7}$$

Comment: Thank you so much this makes a lot more sense!

Comment: Glad to have been of help ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: I do agree that it is Inclusion-Exclusion as done here, but I also have an issue with how the top line of this is written. It isn't for example [*At least one suit missing*] ; it is instead [*Hands with no Diamonds*] $+$ [*Hands with no Clubs*] $+$ [*Hands with no Spades*] $+$ [*Hands With no Hearts*].  As in Thomas Andrews' answer below, we ultimately want the cardinality of [*Hands with no Diamonds*] $\cup$ [*Hands with no Clubs*] $\cup$ [*Hands with no Spades*] $\cup$ [*Hands With no Hearts*], and then we subtract this from ${{52} \choose 7}$.

Comment: @Mike: I don't understand: What you have written amounts to the null set !

Comment: No it does not. If a hand has all 4 suits, then it does not fall into [*Hands with no Diamonds*] $\cup$ [*Hands with no Clubs*] $\cup$ [*Hands with no Spades*] $\cup$[*Hands with no Hearts*]

Comment: @trueblueanil you've confused $\cup$ for $\cap.$ And I agree, $\binom{4}{1}\binom{39}7$ does not count "at least one missing." Otherwise, you wouldn't need the other terms. It **overcounts** "at least one suit missing," which requires the later terms for correction.

Comment: You wrote + signs instead of U signs which confused me.And the formula doesn't end at the top line, see all the lines. In the way I have done it, from all combos, first I have subtracted one suit **without caring whether other suit(s) have  got subtracted or not** , and so on, and so forth, so it *is* at least one suit missing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I can't argue with you on technicalities. If the wording requires minor changes to be technically correct, you are free to correct it. I'll look at my dusty notes tomorrow !

Comment: He wrote $+$ signs for the sum of the counts, and used $\cup$ for the union. The point is $|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|+|A_4|$ is **not** the same as $|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4|.$ The latter is the number of "at least one missing," but the former, which is $\binom41\binom{39}7,$ does not count the cases of "at least one missing."

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: (Similar Q) "Count the number of five card hands. Remove the number of five card hands missing at least a particular suit and which suit that was (among possibly missing more). Add back the number of five card hands missing at least two particular suits, subtracting missing at least three particular suits, etc... You can end at that point since it is impossible to be missing four or more suits at a time here" What's wrong with what I wrote ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328530/what-is-the-probability-that-a-five-card-poker-hand-contains-all-4-suits/4328552#4328552

Comment: Interpreted your way, that answer would be wrong, too. But the "particular suit(s)" phrase, when read carefully, can be interpreted to be correct. Here, they subtract the hands which don't have clubs, the hands which don't have diamonds, etc. $\binom{39}{7}$ counts each of those. But if you subtract $4\binom{39}7$ you are not subtracting the number of hands with at least one suit missing, but a number bigger than that - you are attempting to count that, but you are over counting that number, hence the need for correction terms.

Comment: $[\text{all combos}]-[\text{at least one suit missing}]$ is the exact count you want. There would be no reason to have any terms after that. But your second terms is not $[\text{at least one suit missing}],$ it is an over-count of that value.

Comment: If $N$ is the random variable counting the suits not in your $7$ cards, you can consider $e=\frac{4\binom{39}{7}}{\binom{52}{7}}$ as the expected value of $N.$ So $e=P(N=1)+2P(N=2)+3P(N=3).$ But you are saying $e=P(N>0)=P(N=1)+P(N=2)+P(N=3).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I understand that neither *exactly one missing* nor *at least one missing* correctly reflects the situation. But if I want to write something linguistically rather than in set cardinalities, does *one missing* pass muster ?

Comment: No, the second value, $\binom{4}1\binom{39}7$ can't be seen as counting anything that is useful here. In inclusion/exclusion, the individual sets $|A_1|,\dots,|A_n|$ count things, but if these are all the same, the value $n|A_1|$ doesn't count anything.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Ok, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the set of all $7$-subsets of the deck.

Let $A_i$ be the set of all elements of $A$ that have no card of suit $i.$

Then the inclusion-exclusion is computing:

$$\left|A\setminus(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4)\right|$$

The key is that the size of $A_i$ are all the same, and the sizes of $A_i\cap A_j$ are all the same when $i\neq j.$

So inclusion-exclusion gives:

$$\binom{52}7-\binom{4}1\binom{39}{7}+\binom{4}2\binom{26}7-\binom43\binom{13}{7}$$

We could, in theory, add $\binom44\binom07,$ but that term is zero, so we just drop it.

That's because $|A_i|=\binom{39}7$ for any $i,$ $|A_{i}\cap A_j|=\binom{26}7$ for each pair $\{i,j\},$ etc.

So this wouldn't work if suits consisted of a different number of cards. You'd have to compute the different sizes for each $A_i,$ each $A_i\cap A_j,$ and each $A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k.$ $A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4$ will always be empty.

---

Another way to write this out is to use a generating function.

Let:

$$F(x)=((1+x)^{13}-1)^4=\sum a_ix^i$$

And $a_i$ is the number of ways to deal $i$ cards and get at least one of each suit.

Writing: $$((1+x)^{13}-1)^4=(1+x)^{52}-\binom41(1+x)^{39}+\binom42(1+x)^{26}-\binom43(1+x)^{13}+1$$

We can compute the coefficient of $x^7$ in each term.

This approach might make it easier to compute, say, the number of ways to select $11$ cards where you get at least two cards per suit, giving that we'd want the coefficient of $x^{11}$ in $$((1+x)^{13}-(1+13x))^4$$

This will give a complex formula with $15$ terms. It can be done with inclusion-exclusion, too, but this will be a little cleaner.

Writing $$((1+x)^{13}-(1+13x))^4=\sum_{i=0}^4 \binom{4}i(-1)^i(1+x)^{13(4-i)}(1+13x)^{i}$$

you get the coefficient of $x^n$ is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^4 (-1)^{i}\binom4i\sum_{j=0}^i13^j\binom ij\binom{13(4-i)}{n-j}$$

Comment: Thank you so much this makes so much sense!!

Answer (score 2):

For a direct count of qualifying hands, consider the possible distribution of suits.

Four cards of one suit and one card from each of the other three suits: $$4\times\binom{13}{4}\times13^3=6,283,420$$

Three cards of one suit, two cards of a second suit, and one card from each of the other two suits: $$4\times\binom{13}{3}\times3\times\binom{13}{2}\times13^2=45,240,624$$

Two cards from each of three suits and one card of the fourth suit: $$\binom{4}{3}\times\binom{13}{2}^3\times13=24,676,704$$

This gives a total of $76,200,748$ qualifying hands and a probability of $0.569578$