# What is the probability that 10 cards are drawn from a deck of 52 cards and contain 4 suits?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm not a solid student of probability theory, so I may have a lot wrong.

I would appreciate it if you could point out where I am wrong.

My equation: $\frac{C_{13}^{1}*C_{13}^{1}*C_{13}^{1}*C_{13}^{1}*C_{48}^{6}}{C_{52}^{10}}$

But this result is actually 22.

I can feel that it is a repetition of the molecular situation discussion, but it is still hard to imagine concretely.

Comment: The problem is, as with every other post like yours here, that you are accidentally applying some sort of significance to whether a card was one of the "*guaranteed*" cards of the suit vs if it was one of the "*possible additional cards*" of the suit.  Having picked $A\clubsuit,A\spadesuit,A\heartsuit,A\diamondsuit$ for the first four, and then when picking the extra six you picked the $2$ through $7$ of clubs, this is treated in your count as a different outcome than picking the $2\clubsuit$, the other aces, and then having picked the $A$ and $3$ through $7$ of clubs when picking the last 6.

Comment: For a correct approach, use inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: This is the same error and problem as this: [What is the probability that a five-card poker hand contains all 4 suits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328530/what-is-the-probability-that-a-five-card-poker-hand-contains-all-4-suits) however due to the size of the hand a direct approach will be far too messy to force.  Inclusion-exclusion is also made messier but still feasible.  Recall that in inclusion-exclusion, you will also need to handle triple intersections and quadruple intersections, alternating adding and subtracting as usual for inclusion-exclusion problems.

Comment: As one final mention before leaving this post... while you should certainly match notation with your teacher and peers while interacting with them, I would discourage the use of the $C^k_n$ notation with the smaller number on top as that is too easily confused with the $C^n_k$ notation with the smaller number on bottom.  Unfortunately both are used in various parts of the world.  It may be a case of US-centrism on my part, but I find the $\binom{n}{k}$ notation to be far more common and far less easily confused, and the $C^k_n$ notation among the least common I've seen.